# Do CORS Preflight requests include the request's headers?

Tags: cors

When I send a POST CORS request from a browser, the browser first sends a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

If my POST includes an `Authorization` header, is that header including in the Options request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I send a POST CORS request from a browser, the browser first sends a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.
>
> If my POST includes an Authorization header, is that header including in the Options request?

No. The OPTIONS request will include a header of

```
access-control-request-headers: authorization
```

to indicate that the client software (running in the browser) wants to sent an authorization header, but the header's value itself is not sent until the POST request.